# How to rank features based on an attribute in python?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, python, feature-selection, feature-weighting

I want to rank each attribute based on their ability to influence the dependent attribute(say for instance, "income" ) in the dataset.

In `R`, I have used `Fselector` for ranking the attributes. But I want to do the same using python(along with the different methods available in `Fselector` like information gain, gain ratio, chi2, rank correlation, linear correlation, symmetrical uncertainty). Any specific package available in python(like `Fselector` in `R`) that can help to achieve this?

How can I rank the attributes to show its impact/influence on one of the features?

For example, I have a dataset with 5 columns(name, population, income, illiteracy, area). So I need to rank each column based on "income"(also, one of the column is of type 'str')

I need to get the output as below:(excluding "income")

```
name 0.41

population 0.0

illiteracy 0.0

area 0.0
```

Appreciate your help.Thanks

Comment: The reason this was closed is because it is about coding rather than statistics. The edit did not change that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Random Forest to check for feature importance as follows:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
import numpy as np
#Load boston housing dataset as an example
boston = load_boston()
X = boston["data"]
Y = boston["target"]
names = boston["feature_names"]
rf = RandomForestRegressor()
rf.fit(X, Y)
print "Features sorted by their score:"
print sorted(zip(map(lambda x: round(x, 4), rf.feature_importances_), names), 
             reverse=True)
```

The above code snippet is borrowed from [here](http://blog.datadive.net/selecting-good-features-part-iii-random-forests/).

You can also try Logistic Regression by fitting a Logistic Regression checking the coefficients of different independent variables.

```
log_reg.fit(X, Y)
log_reg.coef_
```